# Android - How would i go about using RelativeLayout with background image scale right on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout

As you can see in the photo I have a scaling problem with my design. Actually there is two problems. One involving a textview and one about scaling. I found out that the easiest solution for layout was to implement a background image to my RelativeLayout. (This may be a stupid approach i don't know.)

As you can see in the images, the text changes position on textview.setText("blabla"). And is creating visual problem. How would I go about fixing this?

Secondly, how would I solve the scaling issue on different devices? My initial plan was to make one background for each size. Like mdpi, hdpi and so on.. But how do I tell the app to choose between background? And is this even possible?

Am I doing it all wrong? :)

[Positioning problem http://chk.no/bue/stackoverflow.png](http://chk.no/bue/stackoverflow.png)

Comment: Why not provide a 9 patch image for each textview instead of a non scalable background? By the way, the os will choose the correct resolution from the resources based on the resolution of the device.

Comment: Could you explain a little further on the "9-patch-image" method?

Comment: 9 patch images are stretchable images. You can set them as background of textviews and they stretch as long as your view needs to fill the space. Look for 9-patch into the docs. What I would do is to arrange your views filling the space you need having several 9-patches as background